# Processing latex? Ie get text bounding boxs etc

Tags: programming

Im looking at the possibility of processing a latex document to get coordinates of element off the page.

For example if I want to get the coordinates of an image, or a heading off a page and output the values.

Things like bounding boxes, character/text/image positions. Access to hierarchy, such as headers, images tags etc.

Is there any library(python, c++ etc?) or tex editor that would allow me to do this type of thing? 
Or am I better off to process a pdf?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301). What exactly do you want to do with these coordinates? Depending on that there may be other options.